# Unable to understand Double behaviour in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, type-conversion

i have below code in playground

```
let a:Double = 5.2
let b:Double = 5.3
print(b-a)
```

if data type is double the result is `0.0999999999999996` but if data type is float then result is `0.1`.please explain why ?

Comment: I have tried 0.1+0.2 but it does not print such long value as 0.30000000000000004

Comment: I am using swift not javascript

Comment: The issue is not language specific.  Swift uses a binary floating point representation and arithmetic according to the IEEE 754 standard (as does JavaScript and many other languages). As explained in the linked-to thread, these values *cannot* represent all numbers exactly. Try `print(a.debugDescription, b.debugDescription, (b - a).debugDescription)` to see that `a` is not exactly 5.2, `b` is not `5.3`, and `b-a` is not `0.1`, for both `Double` and `Float`.

Comment: I think this questions gets asked every day?

Comment: Computers represent numbers in binary. Both 5.2 and 5.3 can be represented precisely in decimal, but not in binary (5.2  in binary is 101.00110011001100... and 5.3 is 101.01001100110011...). Double uses a 64 bit representation, Float uses a 32-bit representation, so the rounding errors are different.

Comment: So how can i get same result as 0.1 with double also.As of now it is showing me result as 0.9999 something

Comment: But in case of Float i get 0.1 not in Double